# Fixing plot scale of windRose of R package

Tags: r, openair

I would appreciate your help.

I am using the function `windRose` of the `openair` package for R. I am doing wind roses for wind  date from many stations, and I need to compare the results from all roses together. The problem is that the `windRose` function fixes the maximum radius of the windrose to a little bit more than the maximum % of counts found in any direction. How can I control the maximum scale of the windrose, lets say putting a fixed maximum of 30% for the max plotting radius instead of the default maximum put by the function and which depends on my data?
I have explored the code of the function but I have not been able to locate the position in the `windRose` function code where I could do this change.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You will be much more likely to receive help if you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and show us the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but...

My `ggplot2` windrose code where `rose` is a data.frame with columns of `wind_speed` and `wind_direction` in degrees:

```
rose <- data.frame(wind_speed=sample(1:25, 1e5, replace=TRUE), 
                   wind_direction=sample(1:360, 1e5, replace=TRUE))

ggplot(rose, 
       aes(x=wind_direction,
           fill=cut(wind_speed, seq(0, 30, 5)))) +
    geom_bar() +
    scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,360),
                       breaks=c(0, 90, 180, 270)) +
    coord_polar() +
    labs(fill='Wind Speed (m/s)') +
    opts(axis.text.y=theme_blank(),
         axis.ticks=theme_blank(),
         axis.title.y=theme_blank(),
         axis.title.x=theme_blank())
```

Answer (score 0):

I coded up something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266780/wind-rose-with-ggplot-r) that would help. You can set the axis limits to whatever you need.