# Windrose with polygon based on the "climatol" package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use an obsolete package of R named "climatol", and I need to modify a bit the function "rosavent" for my purpose.

I have a matrix of mean wind intensities :

```
intensity <- matrix(c(0.20289, 0.14956, 0.24291, 0.35733, 0.59993, 0.89495, 0.71406, 0.38831), nrow=1, ncol=8)
```

and a matrix of mean wind directions :

```
direction <- matrix(c(42.21043, 88.41437, 137.7938, 182.6797, 227.6208, 269.7415, 313.8207, 358.0944), nrow=1, ncol=8)
```

I need that the polygon heights fit the mean wind direction instead of corresponding to the "ang" parameter of the function "rosavent".

[Here](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/climatol/) is the package "climatol". I can also put the function (which is a bit long) within my post if needed.

Any help would be appreciated !

Thank you

**EDIT**

Here is the climatol vs ggplot results, thx to the help of the comments. For the moment Climatol still closer to the result that I want, but I am working on the ggplot improvements.

Climatol :
[image]

GGplot :
[image]

I'm still trying to improve the ggplot code to get sides of polygon instead of circular linkages between heights given by wind intensity/direction.

As usual thank you for your great help and ideas !

Comment: [some advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for creating a reproducible R example in a stackoverflow question. You're much more likely to get an answer. Also, if you're not wedded to `climatol`, there's an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266780/wind-rose-with-ggplot-r) for creating a windrose in `ggplot2` that you can adapt.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I'm gonna modify my post. I already know this post and the associated windrose function (that I use a lot !) but I really need the climatol one for this time.

Comment: I modified the post, don't hesitate to tell me if I'm still bad in the way I present the problem. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: Since the function `rosavent` is not compiled, you can pull the source code right out of the package and modify which arguments are plotted easily enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's what I did, but I got some issues trying to modify the code. I think I got to modify fx and fy, but I didn't make it for the moment, that's why I wonder if someone would have the solution...

Comment: Doc, you've already done most of the work that `rosavent` does; you've summarized for each direction, but by mean intensity, rather than graduated frequency. Now it's just a question of projecting an xy line/area plot into polar coordinates. Seems like more trouble than it's worth to modify `rosavent` to do this. Try this for starters: `library(ggplot2); df <- data.frame(intensity = t(intensity), direction = t(direction)); ggplot(df, aes(direction, intensity)) + geom_area() + coord_polar()`. If it's going in the right direction, it could be massaged into something more 'wind-rosey'.

Comment: Thank you Noah, I'm trying to go in that direction, I'll keep you in thouch ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm close enough to give an answer to my original question I think. I lost my faith in ggplot2 for this purpose, since I couldn't find a way to plot polygons using coord_polar. I discovered an another package fitting my needs, called "plotrix". Anyway here is an example of dataset I used :

```
# Wind-Currents data
intensity_measured <- matrix(c(0.20289, 0.14956, 0.24291, 0.35733, 0.59993, 0.89495, 0.71406, 0.38831), nrow=1, ncol=8)
intensity_simulated <- matrix(c(0.17853, 0.07568, 0.52146, 1.94222, 0.08634, 0.02636, 0.04742, 0.04162), nrow=1, ncol=8)
direction_measured <- matrix(c(42.21043, 88.41437, 137.7938, 182.6797, 227.6208, 269.7415, 313.8207, 358.0944), nrow=1, ncol=8)
direction_simulated <- matrix(c(36.13772, 85.17624, 148.96940, 176.66004, 210.36353, 282.38215, 314.35050, 0.72026), nrow=1, ncol=8)

# Library allowing polygon plot on polar coordinates
library(plotrix)

# Function for plotting wind data by date
polar.plot(rbind(intensity_measured, intensity_simulated),
           rbind(direction_measured, direction_simulated),main="My plot",
           rp.type="p", poly.col=c(rgb(255/255, 215/255, 0, .8),
           rgb(0, 0, 1, .8)), start=90, clockwise=TRUE, radial.labels = "",
           label.pos=NULL, line.col=c("black", "black"),
           radial.lim=c(0,max(rbind(intensity_measured, intensity_simulated))),
           boxed.radial=FALSE)
```

Here we are :

[image]

This is pretty clear, so, now I can compare my measured and simulated winds ! I'm still interested in a solution using ggplot2 if anyone has a brilliant idea ;)

Thanks to the Stackoverflow community, hope this example can help some of you !