# Expand plot region in windroses using ggplot 2 and polar coordination system

Tags: r, ggplot2, rose-plot

I am looking for a solution for the following problem:
Currently I am producing a wind rose plot with ggplot2 following the script provided by Andy Clifton over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266780/wind-rose-with-ggplot-r).

This works perfectly and I am very thankful for the script provided. However I am having one problem. The labels for the X-Axis get truncated by the edge of the plot, especially when plotting in a facet. 
Is there a way to expand the plot so that the text is fully shown?

(an example picture can be found at the link above)

Answer (score 1):

To practice with a windrose, using the data frame at the end, I created the following plot, which has no issues of x-axis labels being truncated. It admittedly doesn't concern wind speeds or a 24-hour framework, as it is intended for amounts paid to two kinds of vendors, but the plot and the data may help others respond more easily.

[image]

```
> dput(lfvendrose)
structure(list(Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), Payee = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Firm", "Vendor"), class = "factor"), 
    Data1 = structure(c(12L, 10L, 8L, 13L, 7L, 9L, 14L, 3L, 5L, 
    17L, 6L, 11L, 2L, 15L, 18L, 2L, 4L, 19L, 1L, 16L, 18L, 2L, 
    15L, 18L), .Label = c("0, 1", "0, 13", "0, 15", "0, 2", "0, 20", 
    "0, 34", "0, 39", "0, 40", "0, 41", "0, 45", "0, 48", "0, 50", 
    "0, 64", "0, 68", "0, 9", "0, 90", "0, 94", "0,11", "0,16"
    ), class = "factor"), Month = structure(c(5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 
    9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 
    6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L), .Label = c("Apr", "Aug", "Dec", 
    "Feb", "Jan", "Jul", "Jun", "Mar", "May", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep"
    ), class = "factor"), Month.1 = structure(c(5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 
    9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 
    6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L), .Label = c("Apr", "Aug", "Dec", 
    "Feb", "Jan", "Jul", "Jun", "Mar", "May", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep"
    ), class = "factor"), Data2 = structure(c(11L, 10L, 6L, 12L, 
    8L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 7L, 15L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 14L, 16L, 1L, 11L, 
    10L, 6L, 12L, 8L, 4L, 13L, 3L), .Label = c("0, 13,1", "0, 13,50", 
    "0, 15, 30", "0, 40, 100", "0, 40,1", "0, 40,3", "0, 40,5", 
    "0, 45, 5", "0, 45,15", "0, 45,2", "0, 50,1", "0, 64, 4", 
    "0, 64,200", "0, 9,150", "0, 94,10", "0,11, 400"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Time", 
"Payee", "Data1", "Month", "Month.1", "Data2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```