# How the wind rose varies by month: Package openair

Tags: r, openair, rose-plot

I have date for 8 years. Sample of my data:

```
structure(list(Data = c("1/1/2015", "1/2/2015", "1/3/2015", "1/4/2015", 
"1/5/2015", "1/6/2015", "1/7/2015", "1/8/2015", "1/9/2015", "1/10/2015", 
"1/11/2015", "1/12/2015", "1/13/2015", "1/14/2015", "1/15/2015", 
"1/16/2015", "1/17/2015", "1/18/2015", "1/19/2015", "1/20/2015", 
"1/21/2015", "1/22/2015", "1/23/2015", "1/24/2015", "1/25/2015", 
"1/26/2015", "1/27/2015", "1/28/2015", "1/29/2015", "1/30/2015", 
"1/31/2015"), no2 = c(3.56, 11.13, 11.84, 4.88, 6.16, 12.56, 
18.99, 24.74, 10.81, 12.7, 6.08, 7.34, 16.88, 16.65, 15.81, 20.78, 
15.03, 11.82, 15.18, 17, 15.21, 13.86, 10.28, 8.34, 11.89, 7.22, 
15.44, 10.55, 8.19, 5.04, 14.65), ws = c(10.84, 3.71, 2.08, 4.59, 
6.18, 2.97, 2.13, 1.22, 1.92, 2.07, 3.09, 4.75, 2.12, 1.8, 1.9, 
1.79, 1.58, 1.86, 1.58, 1.47, 1.7, 2.6, 2.67, 3.21, 1.78, 4.58, 
1.79, 3.1, 3.49, 6.15, 2.59), wd = c(90, 112.5, 112.5, 270, 90, 
135, 112.5, 112.5, 270, 315, 270, 112.5, 112.5, 135, 135, 112.5, 
292.5, 135, 270, 135, 112.5, 112.5, 270, 112.5, 112.5, 112.5, 
112.5, 112.5, 270, 270, 270)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-31L))
```

```
library(openair)

windRose(nitrogen,
         key = list(header="Wind Rose Acri", footer="wind speed",
                    plot.style = c("ticks", "border"),
                    fit = "all", height = 1,
                    space = "top"))

pollutionRose(nitrogen, pollutant = "no2")
```

I want to show how the wind rose varies by month. The same problem ([Wind rose with ggplot (R)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266780/wind-rose-with-ggplot-r)) but tried realised by function from Openair package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert your Data column to a name called `date` with date format and specify `type` argument with "month". `type` according to [documenation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openair/versions/2.7-2/topics/windRose):

> `type` determines how the data are split i.e. conditioned, and then
> plotted. The default is will produce a single plot using the entire
> data. Type can be one of the built-in types as detailed in cutData
> e.g. “season”, “year”, “weekday” and so on. For example, type =
> "season" will produce four plots --- one for each season.
>
> It is also possible to choose type as another variable in the data
> frame. If that variable is numeric, then the data will be split into
> four quantiles (if possible) and labelled accordingly. If type is an
> existing character or factor variable, then those categories/levels
> will be used directly. This offers great flexibility for understanding
> the variation of different variables and how they depend on one
> another.
>
> Type can be up length two e.g. type = c("season", "weekday") will
> produce a 2x2 plot split by season and day of the week. Note, when two
> types are provided the first forms the columns and the second the
> rows.

Please note you only provided one month:

```r
library(openair)
# add month column
nitrogen$date <- as.POSIXct(nitrogen$Data, format = '%m/%d/%Y')
windRose(nitrogen,
         key = list(header="Wind Rose Acri", footer="wind speed",
                    plot.style = c("ticks", "border"),
                    fit = "all", height = 1,
                    space = "top"),
         type = 'month')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Here is an example with build-in data with `type = 'month'`:

```r
library(openair)
windRose(mydata, type = "month")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I want to add that this also applies to `pollutionRose`.

Comment: How can I understand what happened
`Error in if (myby/mymax > 0.9) myby <- mymax * 0.9 : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In checkNum(mydata, vars = c(ws, wd)) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: wd is not numeric, forcing to numeric... 
3: Missing dates detected, removing 365 lines 
4: In max(mydata$x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: In min(mydata$x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
6: In max(logical(0), na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`